# IndexedDB Quota within webview on Android

Tags: android, cordova, webview, indexeddb, quota

IndexedDB seems to be the way forward in Web Apps.

I'd like to use IndexedDB to store lots of large blobs (media files, audio/video) within a cordova web app. I've tried it and IndexedDB outperforms any other storage type that I've found. When I say outperforms, I mean the overhead of calls to store and retrieve data between 5mb and 100mb in a single file/blob.

The problem is within a webview on Android - when the IndexedDB database gets to 750mb (or thereabouts) - I get 'quota' errors.

How do we get past these quota errors? Is there even a way to know what the quota is?

Comment: Indexeddb has a limit